# Check all elements are empty in form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to validate the following form

```
<form method="post" action="#" name="register">
  Name <input type="text" name="name"/><br><br>
  Age <input type="text" name="age"/><br><br>
  Gender <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male"/> M <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female"/> F<br><br>
  Graduate <input type="radio" name="graduate" value="yes"/> YES <input type="radio" name="graduate" value="no"/> NO<br><br>
  Address <textarea name="address"></textarea><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Send" onclick="validate()"/>
</form>
```

i have to validate the following things,
If any field is left empty, popup an alert indicating which box is empty and also check if the age entered is valid (i.e. greater than 15 and less than 50).

i tried below code

```
function validate()
{
  var fields = ["name", "age", "gender", "graduate", "address"]
  var i, l = fields.length;  
  var fieldname;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    fieldname = fields[i];
    if (document.forms["register"][fieldname].value === "") {
      alert(fieldname + " can not be empty");
      return false;
    }
  }
  if (document.forms["register"][age].value>=15 && document.forms["register"][age].value<=50) {
      alert("enter valid age");
      return false;
    }
  return true;
}
```

but this code is only check the name filed and age fields are empty or not other criteria  are not worked (checking radio button , check boxes, address and age limit)

please help me...

Comment: Gender should be a radio not a checkbox

Comment: but i want to check the check boxes also....

Comment: There isn't any code for your other items, having you attempted adding them?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function validate()
{
  var fields = ["name", "age"];
  var radioField=["gender", "graduate"];
  
  var i, l = fields.length,rl=radioField.length;  
  var fieldname;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    fieldname = fields[i];
    if (document.forms["register"][fieldname].value === "") {
      alert(fieldname + " can not be empty");
      return false;
    }
  }
    for (i = 0; i < rl; i++) {
 
    fieldname = radioField[i];
    if (document.forms["register"][fieldname][0].checked == false && document.forms["register"][fieldname][1].checked == false) {
      alert(fieldname + " check one");
      return false;
    }
 
  }
    if (document.forms["register"]["address"].value === "") {
   alert("address can not be empty");
   return false;
 }
  var age =parseInt(document.forms["register"]["age"].value);
  var check =isNaN(age);
  if(check===true){
  alert("please enter number");
  return false;
  }
  if (age >= 15 && age<=50) {
      alert("enter valid age");
      return false;
    }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="#" name="register">
  Name <input type="text" name="name"/><br><br>
  Age <input type="text" name="age"/><br><br>
  Gender <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male"/> M <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female"/> F<br><br>
  Graduate <input type="radio" name="graduate" value="yes"/> YES <input type="radio" name="graduate" value="no"/> NO<br><br>
  Address <textarea name="address"></textarea><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Send" onclick="validate()"/>
</form>
```

error show when you write age between 15 to 50

[image: Error for check age]

if you just oppsite like give error when age is not between 15 to 50 then

```js
function validate()
{
  var fields = ["name", "age"];
  var radioField=["gender", "graduate"];
  
  var i, l = fields.length,rl=radioField.length;  
  var fieldname;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    fieldname = fields[i];
    if (document.forms["register"][fieldname].value === "") {
      alert(fieldname + " can not be empty");
      return false;
    }
  }
    for (i = 0; i < rl; i++) {
 
    fieldname = radioField[i];
    if (document.forms["register"][fieldname][0].checked == false && document.forms["register"][fieldname][1].checked == false) {
      alert(fieldname + " check one");
      return false;
    }
 
  }
    if (document.forms["register"]["address"].value === "") {
   alert("address can not be empty");
   return false;
 }
  var age =parseInt(document.forms["register"]["age"].value);
  var check =isNaN(age);
  if(check===true){
  alert("please enter number");
  return false;
  }
  if (!(age >= 15 && age<=50)) {
      alert("enter valid age");
      return false;
    }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="#" name="register">
  Name <input type="text" name="name"/><br><br>
  Age <input type="text" name="age"/><br><br>
  Gender <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male"/> M <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female"/> F<br><br>
  Graduate <input type="radio" name="graduate" value="yes"/> YES <input type="radio" name="graduate" value="no"/> NO<br><br>
  Address <textarea name="address"></textarea><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Send" onclick="validate()"/>
</form>
```

Comment: age limit is not checked

Comment: write age between 15 to 50 it show alert message that "enter valid age"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
function validate() {
  var fields = ["name", "age", "address"],
    //needs to validate teh check fields separately
    checkfields = ['gender', 'graduate'];
  var i, j, l = fields.length;
  var fieldname, els, valid, form = document.forms["register"];
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    fieldname = fields[i];
    if (form[fieldname].value === "") {
      alert(fieldname + " can not be empty");
      return false;
    }
  }

  l = checkfields.length;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    fieldname = checkfields[i];
    els = form[fieldname].length ? form[fieldname] : [form[fieldname]];
    valid = false;
    for (j = 0; j < els.length; j++) {
      if (els[j].checked) {
        valid = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!valid) {
      alert(fieldname + " can not be empty");
      return false;
    }
  }


  var age = +form.age.value;
  if (!age || age < 15 || age > 50) {
    alert("enter valid age");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<!-- use the validation on the submit event -->
  <!-- Need to return the valid value to stop the default action -->
<form method="post" action="#" name="register" onsubmit="return validate()">
  Name <input type="text" name="name"/><br/><br/>
  Age <input type="text" name="age"/><br/><br/>
  Gender <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male"/> M <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female"/> F<br/><br/>
  Graduate <input type="radio" name="graduate" value="yes"/> YES <input type="radio" name="graduate" value="no"/> NO<br/><br/>
  Address <textarea name="address"></textarea><br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those fields you want them be filled, use required="required" on your html tags, so u donnot hv to use JS for validation.  [example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) . Use JS validation for those requiring value range check etc.